# I have to use ctrl+s everytime to updatde UI . Setstate() not working. Where to use setstate() properly?

Tags: json, http, flutter-layout, setstate, weather-api

I I'm writing a code for weather application, with only two screens. And I'm using **openWeatherApi** to fetch weather data using http protocol from json file which is present on internet, to my weather UI. Now the the issue is that,the data from json is coming perfectly to terminal,but **It does not come to UI screen until I press ctrl+s.The UI does not updates until I press ctl+S**. When I run the code first time It does not show the current weather status(which is in Celsius degree),it just shows null, **a written null on the screen,where current weather should be shown**, and also the image behaves like that as well. Now I'm not getting **is a setstate() issue** or else. I don't know why the UI is not updating.I'm **providing **every file**** that I'm using. Please **Help!**.

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1237], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: weather_ui
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

 
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/getstarted.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: GetStarted());
  }
}
```

**getstart.dart(first screen where a user press a button and moves to the second screen)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/weather_page.dart';

class GetStarted extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetStarted({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GetStartedState createState() => _GetStartedState();
}

class _GetStartedState extends State<GetStarted> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.blueGrey,
                  Colors.black,
                ],
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight,
                stops: [0, 1]),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 180),
                height: 170,
                width: 170,
                child: Image.asset('assets/cloud2.png'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 70),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Weather',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'News',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '& Feed',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Text(
                  'Thinking About Weather Cicumstances!.Get Notified With Latest Weather Updates Here',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.yellow,
                      onPrimary: Colors.black,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      minimumSize: Size(320, 0),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //startApp();
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => WeatherPage()));
                  },
                  child: Text('Get start',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**weather_page.dart(second or main screen where I'm showing the data,and the UI is not Updating.)**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/getstarted.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/weatherApidata.dart';

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WeatherPageState createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  void startApp() async {}

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    ApiData instance = ApiData(location: 'Lahore');
    instance.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => GetStarted()));
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Weather Forcast',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blueGrey, Colors.black],
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight,
                stops: [1, 1]),
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(children: [
            // ClipRRect(
            //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            //Expanded(
            currentWeather(),

            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            nextSevenDaysForcast(),

            alldayforcaast(),

            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Chance of Rain',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            todayWeatherGraph(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }

  Container todayWeatherGraph() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20),
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
          //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Rainy',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Sunny',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text('Heavy',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15)),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/graph2.jpg',
                      width: 323,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                ),
                Text(
                  '10 AM',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text(
                  '12 AM',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('02 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('05 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('07 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Container nextSevenDaysForcast() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Today',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                fontSize: 20),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Tomorrow',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Next 7 Days',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container alldayforcaast() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: double.infinity,
      //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '10 AM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '26',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '12 AM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '27',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '02 PM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '28',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container currentWeather() {
    //Map map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var t = ApiData.temprature;
    var uicon = ApiData.uiicon;
    setState(() {});

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Today',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 170,
              ),
              Text(
                'Thur, 30 Sep',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      //style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,

                      text: t.toString().substring(0, 2),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: '°C',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ))
                  ])),
              SizedBox(
                width: 120,
              ),
              Image.network(
                "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/$uicon@2x.png",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.location_on,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                'MuslimTown,Lahore',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      height: 250,
      width: 370,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white10,
        // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**weatherApidata.dart(here fetching data using http url)**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiData {
  String? location;
  //named constructor for the value of location in  URL
  ApiData({this.location}) {
    location = this.location;
  }

  static double? temprature;
  String? description;
  Map? main;
  static String? uiicon;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final String uri =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$location&appid=2128fd6e36b66857a8329a16ea0bf00f";
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(uri);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    Map temprature_data = data['main'];
    temprature = temprature_data['temp'] - 273.15;

    List weather_data = data['weather'];
    Map weather_main_data = weather_data[0];
    Map main_description = data['main'];
    String getdescription = weather_main_data['description'];
    uiicon = weather_main_data['icon'];

    int pressure = temprature_data['pressure'];

    description = getdescription;
    main = main_description;
    print(main);
    print(uiicon);
    print(description);
    print((temprature).toString().substring(0, 4));
    print(pressure);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling setState in the right place, set state should be called after you have retrieved the data from the api, here is how you can fix that in the weather_page.dart :

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/getstarted.dart';
import 'package:weather_ui/UI/weatherApidata.dart';

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WeatherPageState createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  void startApp() async {}

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    fetchWeatherData();
  }

  Future fetchWeatherData() async
  {
    ApiData instance = ApiData(location: 'Lahore');
    await instance.getData();
    setState(() {});

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => GetStarted()));
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Weather Forcast',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blueGrey, Colors.black],
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight,
                stops: [1, 1]),
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(children: [
            // ClipRRect(
            //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            //Expanded(
            currentWeather(),

            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            nextSevenDaysForcast(),

            alldayforcaast(),

            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Chance of Rain',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            todayWeatherGraph(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }

  Container todayWeatherGraph() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20),
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
          //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Rainy',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Sunny',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text('Heavy',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15)),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/graph2.jpg',
                      width: 323,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                ),
                Text(
                  '10 AM',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text(
                  '12 AM',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('02 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('05 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 25,
                ),
                Text('07 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Container nextSevenDaysForcast() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Today',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                fontSize: 20),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Tomorrow',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Next 7 Days',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container alldayforcaast() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: double.infinity,
      //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '10 AM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '26',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '12 AM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '27',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 150,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/cloud2.png',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          '02 PM',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
                        child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: '28',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30),
                                children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: '°C',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20))
                            ])),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white10,
                // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container currentWeather() {
    //Map map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var t = ApiData.temprature;
    var uicon = ApiData.uiicon;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Today',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 170,
              ),
              Text(
                'Thur, 30 Sep',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      //style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,

                      text: t.toString().substring(0, 2),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: '°C',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ))
                  ])),
              SizedBox(
                width: 120,
              ),
              Image.network(
                "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/$uicon@2x.png",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.location_on,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                'MuslimTown,Lahore',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      height: 250,
      width: 370,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white10,
        // border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white10),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would also like to suggest that you read more about StatefulWidget and avoid using static fields to hold the state of your app.

On way to edit your code to remove the dependency on the static field for DataApi, you should change the DataApi class as follows :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiData {
  String? location;
  //named constructor for the value of location in  URL
  ApiData({this.location}) {
    location = this.location;
  }

  double? temprature;
  String? description;
  Map? main;
  String? uiicon;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final String uri =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$location&appid=2128fd6e36b66857a8329a16ea0bf00f";
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(uri);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    Map temprature_data = data['main'];
    temprature = temprature_data['temp'] - 273.15;

    List weather_data = data['weather'];
    Map weather_main_data = weather_data[0];
    Map main_description = data['main'];
    String getdescription = weather_main_data['description'];
    uiicon = weather_main_data['icon'];

    int pressure = temprature_data['pressure'];

    description = getdescription;
    main = main_description;
    print(main);
    print(uiicon);
    print(description);
    print((temprature).toString().substring(0, 4));
    print(pressure);
  }
}
```

And then in your stateful widget, you add an ApiData property to be part of the state of your widget and wherever you are using the the static field you replace them with fields of the instance of ApiData as follows :

add ApiData property for the state like this :

```
class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {

  ApiData apiData = ApiData(location: 'Lahore');
```

change the fetchWeatherData function to use the instance of getData like this :

```
  Future fetchWeatherData() async
  {
    await instance.getData();
    setState(() {
    });

  }
```

and then use it in the widget building by editing the currentWeather function :

```
  Container currentWeather() {
    //Map map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var t = apiData.temprature;
    var uicon = apiData.uiicon;
```

Please note, that I have kept the code short for the simplicity of the post and showed you only the modification you need to apply.

Comment: Brother that solved my issue with static fields. Thanks a lot for that . But I'm facing issue with non-static fields now. It shows null and also doesn't load the picture. And the UI is not updating even after saving or pressing ctrl+s this time. It would be big help if you help me solve this issue as well.

Comment: the issue is solved, thanks. But one thing that I faced for both the static and non-static fields, is that ,the app takes 2,3 seconds to load data. is it ok?

Comment: That depends on the API you are calling, so there is a  high chance that it's ok. Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as the one that solved your question.